# Two factor authentication via email in keycloak version 22.0.1 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, keycloak, keycloak-services

I need to authenticate my PHP app with keycloak with two factor authentication via email.
I found the library [mesutpiskin/keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator](https://github.com/mesutpiskin/keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator) which support two factor authentication with email.
I had done my all steps which is written in Readme file.

Done - mvn package will create a jar file. copy **keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator.jar** to **keycloak/providers/** inside my keycloak docker container. Its working fine.

But how do I need to perform these steps :

html/code-email.ftl is a html email template. Copy to **themes/base/email/html/**

copy text/code-email.ftl to **themes/base/email/text/**

append messages/*.properties to **themes/base/email/messages/messages_en.properties**

But thers is only themes folder is available **base/email/html** or **base/email/text** subfolder is not available.

Please any one guide me.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to using keycloak, so please take what I say with a grain of salt, and hopefully somebody who is more familiar with it can either confirm that this is correct or provide alternate instructions, but this is what worked for me.

The files in question are located in the keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator codebase at src/main/resources/theme/email-code-theme/email. There you will find directories html, text, and messages.
[directory structure for files in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubV4q.png)

The destination for these files is within your keycloak installation itself, specifically in the themes directory. I copied the files in question so that they ended up at {path to keycloak installation}/themes/base/email, and then followed the location patterns listed in the installation instructions as you included in your question. The end result looked something like this.
[Ending location of files in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q96Vg.png)I'm very new to using keycloak, so please take what I say with a grain of salt, and hopefully somebody who is more familiar with it can either confirm that this is correct or provide alternate instructions, but this is what worked for me.

The files in question are located in the keycloak-2fa-email-authenticator codebase at src/main/resources/theme/email-code-theme/email. There you will find directories html, text, and messages.

[image]

The destination for these files is within your keycloak installation itself, specifically in the themes directory. I copied the files in question so that they ended up at {path to keycloak installation}/themes/base/email, and then followed the location patterns listed in the installation instructions as you included in your question. The end result looked something like this.

[image]

Before I followed these steps, I was getting an error about the template file not being available every time I tried to use the email 2FA provider to authenticate. But now after moving these files as detailed above, I get no errors, the email sends fine, and I am able to complete the authentication process using the code in the generated email. Hope this helps!

Comment: Do I need create the sub dir manually inside my keycloak container themes dir ??

Comment: I had created these sub dir manually inside my keycloak containers themes dir. And when I tset the test mail inside email settings. It gives an error. Failed to send email.
but when removed the themes/base/email/html , themes/base/email/text then it started working.

Any other solution

Comment: And are you using keycloak docker image

Comment: not solving my problem

Comment: Yes, I had to manually create the directories within {keycloak installation directory}/themes. Also, I didn't mention it, but did you run keycloak with the `build` parameter, i.e., `{keycloak installation directory}/bin/kc.sh build`? That step is necessary to make keycloak aware of the new themes.

Comment: like your using keycloak image or what ??
I simply goes inside my container and and navigate to cd opt/keycloak/themes
and make the sub dirs  base/email/html same as base/email/text and same as base/email/messages 

Then I restart my container.

And goes to realm settings -> Email configuration click on Test mail It gives me an error email  Caused by: org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerException: Failed to process template text/email-test.ftl. Did I something went wrong ???

Comment: I'm not using Docker, I used the instructions for [OpenJDK](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-zip) (AKA "Keycloak on bare metal") installation. But I think these steps shouldn't be too much different. If your keycloak is installed in /opt/keycloak, then you might need to run `/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build` to make it aware that you've installed the new templates. That build command causes keycloak to scan for new providers and new templates. If that doesn't work, I'm afraid I don't know what else to try.